# Multichoose with caps on multiplicity

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

A standard multiset coefficient, counting the number of multisets of size $k$ drawn from $n$ elements, is known to be $
\left( \! \binom{n}{k} \! \right) = \binom{n+k-1}{k}.
$

Suppose there is a cap on the multiplicity of each element. For instance, suppose an urn contains 11 red balls, 6 green balls, 2 black balls, and 4 blue balls.  How many ways can you draw a "hand" of 5 balls?

In general, suppose we use $\left( \! \binom{n}{k} \! \right)_{r_1, \dots, r_n}$ to denote the number of size $k$ multisets taken from $n$ elements in which, for each $j=1, \dots, n$, the multiplicity of element number $j$ is at most $r_j$.  Is there a standard name and notation for this?  Is it reducible in closed form to familiar combinatorial entities like binomial coefficients, factorials, etc?

Comment: This is an [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) problem.

Comment: To see the duplicate, note that a multiset of size $k$ from a set of size $n$ can be thought of as an integer vector $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ where $a_1+\dots+a_n=k$. We interpret $a_i$ as the multiplicity of element $i$. Your restriction corresponds to saying $a_i\le r_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.